# All users to have exactly the same date and time

Tags: ios, swift, date, time

So I would like that all my users would have the same date and time no matter their location. Even if they have changed date and time settings the date and time in the application would not change.

At the moment I have constructed a string which is based on every user's 'iPhone time'.

```
let todaysDate: String = {

    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let result = formatter.string(from: date)

    return result
}()
```

My wish is that every user would have EET (Eastern Europe Time).

Comment: you can't user's system time. (i don't know in case jail-break devices)

Comment: The user can change the time on the device (so you can't just get system time), so I'd guess you would have to get the time from a server or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the time zone of your dateformatter to EET if you need the time/date to be independent of user location.

`formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EET")`

However, `Date()` returns the current device time, so if the user changes their date/time setting, you would get wrong results. To always get a correct data, you have to rely on a date fetched from a reliable server.